# Property of twice of a vector minus its orthogonal projection

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection

For a given $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $x_*=\arg\min_{x \in C}\frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|^2$ where $C$ is a convex set.

Can we show the following is nonnegative?
$$
\langle x_*, 2y-x_* \rangle \geq 0.
$$

**My thoughts**

By writing $2y=y+y$ and adding and subtracting manipulation, the above can be written as the following:
$$
\langle x_*, 2y-x_* \rangle= -\|x_*-y\|^2+\|y\|^2.
$$

When $y \in C$ we are done because $x*=y$, but when $y \notin C$ what can we do?

I can intuitively see when $y \notin C$, $\|y\|$ is greater than $\|x_*-y\|$ but I cannot show it algebraically.

---

**Edit**

Assume $C$ is not singleton set and contains the zero vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the original (unedited question), let $y = (0,0)$, $y \not\in C$, and use what you've already found to disprove the statement.

If $C$ contains the zero vector (that is, $0\in C$), then by the arg min condition, $\|x_*-y\|^2\leq\|0 - y\|^2=\|y\|^2$.
Then $0 \leq -\|x_*-y\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = 
\langle x_*, 2y-x_* \rangle$.

This works even if $C$ is a singleton, though of course non-singletons work too.

Comment: Can you please show it when 0 is in $C$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $C=\{-1\}, y = 0$ then $x_* = -1$, but $x_*(2y-x_*) = (-1)(0-(-1)) = -1 < 0$.

Comment: Is $C$ a convex set?

Comment: You may need to review your convex set definition.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question.

Comment: Evolving questions bother me.

Comment: I am sorry bothering you.

Comment: No problem :-).

Answer (score 0):

For the updated question, assuming $C$ contains the origin, the statement is indeed true — and it doesn’t depend on $C$ being non-singleton, and not much on $C$ being convex. We do however need to also assume $C$ is closed, for the $\mathrm{argmin}$ in the question to make sense..

As you say, the desired inequality is equivalent to showing $\|y\|^2-\|y-x_*\|^2 \geq 0$, or equivalently $\|y-x_*\| \leq \|y\|$.

The definition of $x_*$ is as “the closest point in $C$ to $y$” — some point with minimal distance exists by closedness of $C$, and it’s unique if we’re assuming $C$ is convex.  So since the origin is in $C$, $x_*$ is at least as close to $y$ as the origin is.  But that’s exactly saying that $\|y-x_*\| \leq \|y\|$, as required.